# Printing dictionary as table without importing module

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I have the following two dictionaries:

```
stats_dict = {
  "PO1": {
    "congruent": {
      "mean": 0.6205138,
      "stdev": 0.07207165926839758,
      "true_percentage": 0.8333333333333334
    },
    "incongruent": {
      "mean": 0.6205138,
      "stdev": 0.07207165926839758,
      "true_percentage": 0.8333333333333334
    }
  },
  "PO2": {
    "congruent": {
      "mean": 0.6205138,
      "stdev": 0.07207165926839758,
      "true_percentage": 0.8333333333333334
    },
    "incongruent": {
      "mean": 0.6205138,
      "stdev": 0.07207165926839758,
      "true_percentage": 0.8333333333333334
    }
  },
  "PO3": {
    "congruent": {
      "mean": 0.6205138,
      "stdev": 0.07207165926839758,
      "true_percentage": 0.8333333333333334
    },
    "incongruent": {
      "mean": 0.6205138,
      "stdev": 0.07207165926839758,
      "true_percentage": 0.8333333333333334
    }
  }
}

group_stats_dict = {
     "congruent": {
              "mean": 0.68699328,
              "stddev": 0.98465454,
              "pecentage_correct": 0.98
           },
     "incongruent": {
              "mean": 0.78699328,
              "stddev": 0.99465454,
              "pecentage_correct": 0.98
           }
}
```

What I am looking to do is print the results out formatted in a table in the console.

I have the following code so far:

```
    stats_dict = {}
    group_stats_dict = {}

    print ("            CONGRUENT                      INCONGRUENT")
    print ("PARTICIPANT MEAN     STDDEV   %CORRECT     MEAN    STDDEV    % CORRECT")
    for d in stats_dict.keys():
        print(d)
        for m in stats_dict[k]:
            print(m)
```

I would like the output to look like this in the console (where group is the printed group_stats dictionary.):

```
            CONGRUENT                           INCONGRUENT
PARTICIPANT MEAN        STDDEV      % CORRECT   MEAN        STDDEV      % CORRECT   
P01         0.620       0.072       0.83        0.620       0.072       0.83
P02         0.620       0.072       0.83        0.620       0.072       0.83
GROUP       0.686       0.984       0.98        0.786       0.994       0.98
```

I am having difficulty getting the data to be positioned under the correct headings my output at the moment is like this:

```
            CONGRUENT                      INCONGRUENT
PARTICIPANT MEAN     STDDEV   %CORRECT     MEAN    STDDEV    % CORRECT
P01
congruent
incongruent
P02
congruent
incongruent
P03
congruent
incongruent
P04
congruent
incongruent
P05
```

All help greatly appreciated. Let me know if you have any questions or anything needs adding to my question.

Can I format data to 3 decimal places as well something like this?

```
    for participant,value in stats_dict.items():
        print(
            participant,
            value.get("congruent","{:.3f}").get("mean"),
            value.get("congruent","{:.3f}").get("stdev"),
            value.get("congruent",{}).get("percentage_correct"),
            value.get("incongruent",{}).get("mean"),
            value.get("incongruent",{}).get("stdev"),
            value.get("incongruent",{}).get("percentage_correct")
        )
```

Comment: Try python's textwrap to fill spaces https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stats_dict = {}
group_stats_dict = {}

print ("            CONGRUENT                      INCONGRUENT")
print ("PARTICIPANT","MEAN","STDDEV","%CORRECT","MEAN","STDDEV","% CORRECT")
for participant,value in stats_dict.items():
  print(
       participant,
       value.get("congruent",{}).get("mean"),
       value.get("congruent",{}).get("stddev"),
       value.get("congruent",{}).get("pecentage_correct"),
       value.get("incongruent",{}).get("mean"),
       value.get("incongruent",{}).get("stddev"),
       value.get("incongruent",{}).get("pecentage_correct")
  )

print(
       "GROUP",
       group_stats_dict.get("congruent",{}).get("mean"),
       group_stats_dict.get("congruent",{}).get("stdev"),
       group_stats_dict.get("congruent",{}).get("true_percentage"),
       group_stats_dict.get("incongruent",{}).get("mean"),
       group_stats_dict.get("incongruent",{}).get("stdev"),
       group_stats_dict.get("incongruent",{}).get("true_percentage")
)
```

As suggeted in comments use textwrap to format spaces for answer

Comment: you might also try texttable http://pydoc.net/texttable/1.2.1/texttable/

Comment: That's great thanks! I want to be able to format the data to 3 decimals places can I do something like that above? Have a look at what I have added to the bottom of my question

Comment: no you shoud do like "{0:.3f}".format(value.get("congruent",{}).get("mean"))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.format` to format your lines:

```
...
print ('{:<12}{:<9}{:<9}{:<13}{:<8}{:<10}{}'.format("PARTICIPANT", "MEAN", "STDDEV", "%CORRECT", "MEAN", "STDDEV", "% CORRECT")
for d in stats_dict.keys():
    line = [d]
    for i in 'congruent', 'incongruent':
        for j in ('mean', 'stdev', 'true_percentage'):
            line.append(stats_dict[d][i][j])
    print('{:<12}{:<9.3}{:<9.3}{:<13.2}{:<8.3}{:<10.3}{<13.2}'.format(*line))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you exactly what you want.

```
for d in stats_dict:
value = stats_dict[d]
s = d
    for element in value:
        val = value[element]
        s+=' '*9+"{0:.2f}".format(val['mean'])+' '*5+"{0:.2f}".format(val['stdev'])+' '*5+"{0:.2f}".format(val['true_percentage'])
    print(s)
```

And for the second dictionary, you will just need the inner loop.